# Inkscape: Change font for groups

Tags: inkscape

In Inkscape, I'm trying to design a calendar. I have a grid of numbers (days of the month). I want to change the typeface of all the numbers I'm working with.  Is there a way to do this in a single step?

Currently, I've to select each number with the text tool and change the font for it. This is slow and painful.

Note: I forgot to add that the texts are grouped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select one of the texts you want to change, then go to **Edit >  Select Same > Object Type**.

If you fancy keyboard shortcuts, you can simply select the first text object and then use 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You could double click the group with the Select Tool (F1), to enter the group. Then click and drag to select all the items in the group, whether text or not.  Then select the Text tool, and change the font.  Double click with the Select Tool (F1) outside the group to exit the group.

For example:

[image]

Comment: This worked well. I just had to ungroup my text.

Comment: You don't need to ungroup anything.  If you have a group inside a group, double clicking will enter the group

Comment: That's interesting. Didn't know this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the other options I found was to use the Replace Font extension. Extensions --> Text --> Replace font.

The tool is a little crude and doesn't seem to work properly when applied to selected objects.